# Hiding the table view when the user touches any where in the view

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

Iam creating a table when the user clicks on one button like dropdown list.I have text fields and textvies are there on the same view ,i want to hide that table view when the user touches on any where in the view or any textfields or textviews.please help me any one knows

Comment: I used text field delegate methods hiding the table when the user clicks on any textfield but i want when the user touches on view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect if the user clicked on the view you should use the `touchesBegan` method.
To detect if the user clicked inside a `UITextField` you should declare your view as the delegate and implement the method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

For UITextView, you should implement

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

In these methods you simply hide your tableview.